# OpenGL Depth Calculation for Bounding Boxes

Tags: opengl, linear-algebra

I´m writing an opengl app which uses transparency/translucency algorithms based on depth ordering.

My first approach calculates bounding box center distance to camera for all the objects, but i realized that one bounding box can be closest to camera than other, but its center is farthest.

The orientation of the boxes can be different so axis aren't aligned.

[image]

How can i calculate correctly bounding box distance to camera?

Comment: Is the box axis-aligned?

Comment: Not necessarily, its matrix transformation can be different.

Comment: You need to define what do you mean by what is the distance from a bounding box to a camera, it is usually the distance from the center to the eye position, otherwise, a box will have multiple distances to the camera. Maybe it isn't distance from the center what do you want. But actually the nearest point to the camera? Or you need to project them on the "most significant plane" first then do you calculations.

Comment: are both of the objects transparent ?

Comment: Yes, both of the objects are transparent.

Answer (score 1):

Calculating the distance from `camera` to `centre` for each OBB (oriented bounding box) involves the performance hungry `sqrt` due to the nature of the Euclidean distance function; also you need the closest box from the camera for which approaching the problem by mesauring the distance to centre makes little sense.

### Alternative Methods

#### Z-sorting

If you know the vertices of the boxes in camera space, sorting them by Z would give you the closest one. The box containing that point would be the one closest to the camera. However, since OBBs are usually stored by their centre, orientation and extents, one wouldn't readily have the vertices in camera space; hence it usually requires transforming the vertices of box from box space to the camera space for all vertices of all boxes; this would be costly, perhaps if performed on the GPU, it might be OK.

#### Intersection Testing

This is the alternative I can think of, that is perhaps faster than sorting but less accurate, is to perform a fast ray-obb intersection testing on those boxes (with `ray.origin = camera` and `ray.direction = obb.centre - camera`). Each test would return you a `t` the distance along the vector where the hit on that box occurs; scaling the `ray` with `t` and taking only its Z component would essentially give you the projection of the vector on the Z-axis (this would be the Z coordinate of the point where the ray hits the box); the one with the least Z component will be the closest box from the camera along the Z direction.

[This page](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/miscellaneous/clicking-on-objects/picking-with-custom-ray-obb-function/) has both the algorithm and the implementation of ray-obb test; it uses the [Kay-Kajiya's slab method described in Real-Time Rendering](http://www.realtimerendering.com/intersections.html).

Comment: you can get away sorting by `distance**2` instead of using `distance`, without using `sqrt()`.

Comment: +1 However, distance from the camera to centre doesn't solve the OP's problem; that's the exact problem of the question; hence I proposed the other 2 solutions.

Comment: What ray are you using for the intersection?

Comment: The ray is the one from the camera to the OBB centre; that's the reason I said this would only be an approximation. To find the actual ones, the right thing to do would be to take the edges of OBB in some space and sort them there i.e. the first method in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The best approximation can be done by sorting the objects using the farthest OBB point Z-component in camera space (the point with the highest/lowest Z-component in camera space depending on handedness) and hence comes the name Z-sorting. Also you can use a squared distance just fine.

Remember that when issuing a draw commands you need to render one of them first (you can't draw them partially unless you break each of them to separate objects.

In your case  object1 should be drawn first, and notice that it has the farthest point along the camera axis.

The algorithm in a nutshell:

- Transform each bounding box points into camera space.
- Find the farthest point along the camera Z axis point for each box. This will become the depth key for each bounding box
- Sort the boxes using their depth keys found.
- Draw the objects back to front.

<sub>P.S. I am yet to think of a case where this might fail that's why I said approximation.</sub>

Comment: What if object 2 extended much farther to the left, so that it had the farthest point?

Comment: @Wyzard notice: the highest/lowest Z-component in camera space.

Comment: I think Wyzard has a point. We know that object 1 should be drawn before object 2 (so that we can see object 1 though object 2), due to the way the two objects "overlap" as seen from the camera. If we only look at the point furthest away of each object to determine which should be drawn first, as you suggest, it works fine in the example from the question, because the back of object 1 is furthest away from the camera. But imagine that object 2 was extended a bit (or object 1 shortened a bit) so that the back of object 2 is now furthest away from the camera. Then obj2 will be drawn before obj1.

Comment: Does not seem to be possible by just looking at points. Good short description at https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Transparency_Sorting#How_to_Sort. Must look at "the 'span' of the two objects" somehow...

Comment: @Bjarke well, this is only an approximation, as I mentioned in the answer, this is in general a hard problem, and from my experience games usually try to avoid edge cases.

Comment: @concept3d You are right. It is a good approximation (i gave an upvote) - but i think it is important to mention that there are cases where it fails (considering the "P.S." and Wyzards comment). The OP's center-point approach is probably equally good, and i think his question was how to handle the edge cases. But yeah, if you can't live with the artifacts from the "simple" approaches, it probably becomes a quite complex problem. And it looks like many game engines just use a simple approach and just avoid placing objects in such way that the artifacts occurs...